# How to use a list as a stack in Scala

Tags: scala

I'm trying to work on Stack in Scala , I've done the Stack **val s = Stack [Int]** in the Class and it works perfectly , but I've been asked to use a List that works as a Stack , how can that be made ?

```
  import scala.collection.mutable.Stack
  object string_Search
  {
  def main(args:Array[String])
  {
  trait push extends Stack {
  def push(i:Int) {
    s.push(i)
    println(s)
  }
}
trait pop extends Stack {
  def pop() {
    s.pop()
    println(s)
  }
}
trait view1 extends Stack {
  def view() {
    println(s)
  }
}
class Stack {
  protected val s = List[Int]()
}
val b = new Stack with push with pop with view1
println("Filling the Stack")
b.push(15)
b.push(20)
b.push(25)
b.push(30)
println("\nDeleting from the Stack")
b.pop()
b.pop()
b.pop()
println("\nOutput")
b.view()
   }
  }
```

Comment: A `List` in Scala is a stack.

Comment: How can I add (push) and delete (pop) from the List ?

Comment: `push` = `prepend` - `peak` = `head` - `pop` = `head` + `tail`

Comment: PS: Your example code is weird. Don't know why you overcomplicate your API so much. Interfaces (traits) with single method are used when are needed but for such simple API it is rather overenginering.

Answer (score 1):

`scala.List` is immutable collection and it means you cannot push or pop like in ordinary `mutable.Stack`. You will create new Lists every time you will change it.

```
//it is immutable, then we need to use var instead of val
var stack = List.empty[Int]

//we can always assign fresh value to it. It is immutable... this is the only thing we can do here.
stack = List(1,2,3)

//peek() will look like this
def peek() = stack.head

//push(5) will assign new list that has prepended our value:
def push(x:Int) = stack = 5 :: stack

//pop() will be slightly complicated:
def pop() = {
  val popped = stack.head
  stack = stack.tail
  popped
}
```

PS: probably it is not good idea to write such functions that operate on global varible. This is just for showcase... in real code you will use just `List` or `Seq` Api directly.